# Is it wrong to say: He occupies the bathroom

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, questions

Is it wrong to say:

> "He occupies the bathroom, so I cannot come in"

I heard the phrase:

> "The bathroom is occupied, so I cannot come in."

So I wondered if I also can say it the other way.

Thank you

Comment: For most verbs, a "simple present" denotes either timeless or habitual action: use the "present continuous" for an activity happening at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong, but it is not a usual usage. Firstly, because the bathroom is being used for some significant time period, "he is occupying the bathroom" would be better. But this too sounds unnatural.
Common-use expressions might be:

"The bathroom is occupied, so...."

"He is using the bathroom, so..."

"Fred is in the bathroom, so..."